# Spring Data Neo4j MappingException: Field with primary id is null for entity

Tags: spring-boot, uuid, spring-data-neo4j

I have a node entity class that is extending an abstract class which is in turn extending another abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    @Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
    protected UUID uuid;
}

public abstract class AbstractBayModel extends AbstractModel{
     .....//more protected fields
}

public class Person extends AbstractBayModel{
    private String name;
    .//more code
    .
    .
}

@Service
//Has a reference to a repository
public class PersonService{
   public void add(Person person){
      repository.insert(person);
   }
}
```

now when I invoke the service class's add() method, I am getting the following error.

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Field with primary id is null for entity model.Person@41a45331
```

I have tried to alter the service method as follows  and still get the same error:

```
public void add(Person person){
   person.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID();
   repository.insert(person);
}
```

I am using the following  spring dependencies

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Would be mighty obliged if anyone can assist.

regards

Comment: What happens in your `insert` method? Could you please provide this code also?

Comment: Thanks for the response @meistermeier, I then spent the greater part of Saturday afternoon tracing the error. Seems my issue was setting the Primary Key (uuid) in an abstract super class. I then moved the uuid to the entity class itself and I can now persist to the graph. I dont know if there is a way of making neo4j recognise inherited primary key fields from an inherited abstract class.

Comment: could you try with repository.save(person). Also share the debug logs of application.

Comment: Thanks @Vipul, as indicated in my subsequent follow up post, I managed to locate the source of the problem. Thanks once again for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to persist an entity with custom-object-properties.
Neo4j-OGM only supports

> any primitive, boxed primitive, String or arrays thereof,
> essentially anything that naturally fits into a Neo4j node property.

I replaced all properties with the supported analogs leaving id as the only non-naturally fitting field:

```
@Id @Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
private UUID uuid;
```

It worked for me, I hope it helps someone else.